# What qualities makes someone a strong applicant for an editorial position in math books in a publishing company?

Tags: job-search, job, editors, copy-editing, springer

I'm in the process of applying for an editorial position in Mathematics Books, where the key responsibilities are as follows:

*Evaluate book proposals and manage the peer-review process

*Liaise with authors throughout the publication process, including negotiating contractual conditions

*Collaborate with editorial boards to evaluate manuscript submissions

*Coordinate with internal departments such as production, marketing, and sales

*Establish and maintain a network of relationships with academics

*Attend international conferences and visit universities for acquisition

*Achieve annual publishing goals

And the requirements are as follows:

**Essential:**

*Postgraduate degree in Mathematics or related field

*Excellent written and spoken English

*Strong communication and organizational skills

*Ability to work independently and as part of a team

*Availability to travel to universities and international conferences

*Track record of working to deadlines and delivering results

**Desirable:**

*PhD in Mathematics or related field

*International experience (study or work abroad)

*Working knowledge of LaTeX

Now I've done a PhD in math with published papers, traveled for conferences and worked internationally, and also have decent knowledge of LaTeX. However, **I'm sure almost all the applicants will have these**, so these perhaps won't be the deciding criteria. Hence I wonder what other qualities a good editor will have to possess? For example, **I reviewed a paper for a journal published under this company, should including that have a positive effect?** Anything else, or any other experience that'll make someone a good applicant for this position? I'm trying to write a letter of motivation and I'm trying to go through my experience and relate them to those of a good editor, hence this question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Teamwork, working with different kinds of people, ability to overcome difficulties and get things done (this does not include mathematics research), initiative, any kinds of experiences outside academic mathematics. See the list of skills and qualities in the ad.

Reviewing a paper is a good experience, but whether the journal is published by this publisher or not makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at your SE profile. You seem to have had a varied and interesting mathematical career, which should be a plus. You seem to have checked the necessary skills boxes.

If I were looking at your application I would want to know why *this particular job* was what you wanted to do next. Your CV doesn't suggest that trajectory. I think you should use your cover letter to show why you want to be an editor, not just that your experience will make you a better one.

Good luck,

That letter is also the place where you show that you can write well yourself.

Comment: Thank you - that's indeed a great point, I'll certainly tailor my cover letter accordingly, thank you!